# Uploading file as public to S3 in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kotlin

I am developing an Android application using Kotlin. I am trying to upload file to the AWS S3 bucket. I could upload to the file to the Bucket successfully.  But the problem is that the file is uploaded as private. Instead I want it to be uploaded and set public as well.

This is my code

```
private fun uploadPhotoToS3(path : String){
        doAsync {
            AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(applicationContext).execute()

            val s3Client = AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().credentialsProvider)
            val transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
                    .context(applicationContext)
                    .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().configuration)
                    .s3Client(s3Client)
                    .build()
            val uploadObserver = transferUtility.upload("public/testing.jpg", File(path))

            uploadObserver.setTransferListener(object : TransferListener{
                override fun onStateChanged(id: Int, state: TransferState?) {
                    if(TransferState.COMPLETED == state){
                        Log.i("UPLOAD_STATE", "COMPLETED")
                    } else {
                        Log.i("UPLOAD_STATE", "CHANGED")
                    }
                }

                override fun onProgressChanged(id: Int, bytesCurrent: Long, bytesTotal: Long) {

                }

                override fun onError(id: Int, ex: Exception?) {
                    Log.i("UPLOAD_ERROR", "Unable to upload file")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

How can I modify it to set the file to public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/s3/transferutility/TransferUtility.java#L476

```
val uploadObserver = transferUtility.upload("public/testing.jpg", File(path), CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
```

> Additional

I tried the above solution. But it was returning 403 error. Instead of using cognito credentials provider, I had to use the AWS Basic Credentials Provider with the Access Key and the Secret Key.

Comment: Got this error . 10-15 23:19:19.599 29558-29833/com.thegoodyard.waiyanhein.thegoodyard E/UploadTask: Error encountered during multi-part upload: 4 due to Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 2348F3C66BE0BAB3)
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 2348F3C66BE0BAB3), S3 Extended Request ID: OuzolfzNeNAHvlDq3SdeU8FoYjy7vqPRDB3eVMcFdFoLQn+tZC3GfGjI5lKlwxaestkPA2oXpOk=

Answer (score 0):

[Set the object's access control list](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference//com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CannedAccessControlList.html#PublicRead) to [PublicRead](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference//com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CannedAccessControlList.html#PublicRead).

Comment: But, how can I possibly do it in Kotlin? Cannot even find a method or parameter for it.

Comment: My answer links to the documentation for Android.

Comment: val uploadObserver = transferUtility.upload("public/testing.jpg", File(path), CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead) Ref: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/s3/transferutility/TransferUtility.java#L476

Comment: Got this error . 10-15 23:19:19.599 29558-29833/com.thegoodyard.waiyanhein.thegoodyard E/UploadTask: Error encountered during multi-part upload: 4 due to Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 2348F3C66BE0BAB3) com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 2348F3C66BE0BAB3), S3 Extended Request ID: OuzolfzNeNAHvlDq3SdeU8FoYjy7vqPRDB3eVMcFdFoLQn+tZC3GfGjI5lKlwxaestkPA2oXpOk= –

Comment: Did this answer resolve your issue? You have a way to set the access control, and your new issue (un-related to this question) is dealing with permissions being set incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "Access Denied" error: try using `aws-sdk-android-s3 2.7.3` instead of the latest `2.7.5`. The issue is tracked here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/548